# Adding multiple tappable shapes to UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibezierpath

I have a floor plan with many exhibitor stands.  When a `UIView` loads, a `UIImage` is displayed with the floor plan and a database is checked for a list of exhibitors and their locations. The locations are loaded into an array and a `UIButton` is created for each exhibitor and placed over the floor plan where their stand is. When tapped, this button will show information about that exhibitor.

Here is a screenshot of the floor plan with boxes where the buttons are rendered.

[image]

This works fine as it is BUT I need the buttons to be irregular shapes (triangles, pentagons, circles etc). So I need a way of drawing these shapes and having them clickable in the same way the buttons were.

I have created a test class which generates a `UIView` which contains the shape and added it to my original `UIView`.  I get the feeling this may not be the correct way to do this as I will need to have many buttons on the screen and this would mean many views stacked on each other.  I don't know how I could check which shape was tapped as the `UIViews` would overlap each other.

Can all the shapes be drawn on one view and then the view added?  What is the best approach to this?

Comment: First off understand that you can draw transparent buttons over the floor plan, vs visible butons.  (I assume you're doing this, but just to be sure...)  Next, you can place one button (or simply a view that doesn't transmit presses) over another button to "hide" the "lower" button from presses.  This would let you do an L-shaped button, eg.  You can also position two buttons together to produce an L-shape, routing their presses to the same function.  I think if you want to detect presses in an "odd" shape, though, you need to intercept the touch events and calculate their coordinates.

Comment: My current model has transparent buttons drawn onto the floor plan.  This idea works great is the buttons are regular shapes.  I think your last suggestion maybe the kind of thing i need.

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking I'd throw out the buttons entirely and use touch events.  Come up with a numbered algorithm for each shape, and have each event "filter" through the algorithms, maybe after selecting a subset of candidates by "quadrants" or some such.

Comment: With potentially 250 shapes to loop through, would these maths be carried out reasonably fast?

Comment: First qualify by checking the bounds of the square that surrounds the shape -- this check goes really fast.  And, as I said, you can divide the floor into sections and first select a section.

Comment: I'd create a MyButton class which accepts event coordinates and returns "hit" or "miss".  It would only check the rectangle boundaries.  Then subclass with MyTriangleButton, etc that first does the `super` check, and, if that's a "hit", runs the appropriate computations to see if the hit is inside the triangle.  Or you could just put the equivalent info in a table (and use a `switch`, eg, to select the algorithm) and skip the objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end this is what I did:

- Looped through all of the stand shapes I needed to have and created a dictionary with UIBezierpath of their coordinates on the floorplan image and the standNo for the shape.
- I then added these dictionaries to an array.
- When the screen was tapped I would note the X and Y of the tap position and looped through the array of dictionaries and it checked if the UIBezierpath contained a point made up of the X and Y tapped coordinates.
- If a shape was found that had the X and Y coordinates within its bounds I would draw a CAShapelayer using the UIBezierpath and adding a fillColor so it showed up on the map.  An alertView was then displayed which showed more information about the exhibitor.

This method seemed WAY more efficient than actually drawing out hundreds of UIButtons or even CAShaplayers and even with 300+ areas on the floorplan to check through the process appears instant.

Comment: do you have any proof, that your solution is more efficient? raster graphics consume a lot of memory, as each pixel is represent by 3 or 4 bytes.

Comment: I beleive this method is quicker as nothing is actually ever drawn.  Only Bezierpaths made of points (between 3 and 9 in my case) are stored in the array.  Previous examples described actually drawing CAShapeLayers or UIButtons whereas my example simply has, what is effectively a list of points in an array.  I am happy to be corrected and edit the answer accordingly.  But please note I did say 'seemed' as during usage it was significantly quicker for me on both the simulator and a test iPad2.

Comment: I think you are doing something wrong. a shape layer is lightweight and also do not cotain of much more than a path. but it gives you the advantage to directly intercept interaction events without iterating over a list of paths again and again.

Comment: I had assumed that a UIBezierpath (which is just a start location and subsequent points) would be more 'lighweight' than a CAShapeLayer which has more properties?  Also, would I not have to cycle through the CAShapelayers to find out which one's bounds the tap event occurred in?

Comment: *Also, would I not have to cycle through the CAShapelayers to find out which one's bounds the tap event occurred in?* If you'd did correct hit testing with views,no, as the touched view will raise it hands to yell "Ouch, you hit me". But maybe Duncan C, Hot Licks, I and our combined reputation of about ~65K got all wrong and you have the better solution.

Comment: What an odd comment.  If you read what I have been saying all along, I wrote that the method I used 'seemed' better and I 'believed' it to be so.  Your approach and that of the other posters was actually different, no?  You suggested CAShapelayers and they both suggested UIButtons.  I needed irregular shapes and so UIButtons would not have been simple to implement, certainly far less simple than the approach I ended up with that involved looping through a very simple array.  ALso, your method of hit testing using triangles, you think that is a better approach?  What are the advantages?

Comment: listen, I cannot teach you programming in comments. but you should intuitively understand that it is much better, if an object can identify it was tabbed than you circle through an obscure list on and on. Specially if you maybe once to introduce different kind of triggers, you'll be in trouble, as you made inheritance quite hard already. if you can't stand that more experience programmers criticize your code and doubt the claims you make, you should not be using stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of UI the cleanest thing to do is to use actual buttons. Set their type to custom, and set their image property to the image you want to display. That way the buttons handle highlighting correctly, and manage IBActions just like regular buttons. You can set all the buttons to point to the same action, and use tag values to figure out which button is which.

You can create these buttons either from code or in IB - whichever fits your design better.

You could also do this with custom views or a single view that has drawing on it. IF you use views for each booth, you would need to attach a tap gesture recognizer to each view, and set it's userInteractionEnabled flag to YES.

If you want to use a drawing for the entire floor plan, you would need to add a tap gesture recognizer to the drawing view, and then interpret the coordinates of the tap to figure out which image it lands on.

Comment: Currently, the floor plan image has all the squares/rectangles/triangles etc drawn on it and I am simply putting transparent buttons over the top of them (I know exactly where they should go as the outline coordinates have been recorded and entered into a database as a comma separated string.  I think your last suggestion sounds promising.  Can I just wait for someone to tap the screen, make a note of the coordinates and check that position against an array (of arrays?) to see if it fits inside a 'shape'?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. However, you won't get the button highlighting user feedback that you would get with transparent buttons. If you are already creating transparent buttons, why not stick with that approach?

Comment: If you decide to go with figuring out the tap coordinates yourself, You may need to convert the tap coordinates from one view's coordindate system to another. Take a look at the class overview for UIView in the Xcode help system. There are a whole family of methods for converting coordinates between the coordinate systems of different views.

Answer (score 0):

override
`- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`
method of your map representer view. So you will be able to compare current touch location with all of your shapes, and calculate in which shape your touch point is laying. There different approach for different shapes (e.g [**is point inside a rectangle?**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190111/how-to-check-if-a-point-is-inside-a-rectangle))

Comment: Would I have to basically store all of the shape's coordinates in an array and when the screen is tapped, loop through the array to find what shape had been touched?

Comment: @Ryan yes, it that what i meant.

Answer (score 0):

ole has a great project: [OBShapedButtons](https://github.com/ole/OBShapedButton). He achieves it by checking the alpha value of the touched pixel and overwriting `-pointInside:withEvent:`

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    // Return NO if even super returns NO (i.e., if point lies outside our bounds)
    BOOL superResult = [super pointInside:point withEvent:event];
    if (!superResult) {
        return superResult;
    }

    // Don't check again if we just queried the same point
    // (because pointInside:withEvent: gets often called multiple times)
    if (CGPointEqualToPoint(point, self.previousTouchPoint)) {
        return self.previousTouchHitTestResponse;
    } else {
        self.previousTouchPoint = point;
    }

    BOOL response = NO;

    if (self.buttonImage == nil && self.buttonBackground == nil) {
        response = YES;
    }
    else if (self.buttonImage != nil && self.buttonBackground == nil) {
        response = [self isAlphaVisibleAtPoint:point forImage:self.buttonImage];
    }
    else if (self.buttonImage == nil && self.buttonBackground != nil) {
        response = [self isAlphaVisibleAtPoint:point forImage:self.buttonBackground];
    }
    else {
        if ([self isAlphaVisibleAtPoint:point forImage:self.buttonImage]) {
            response = YES;
        } else {
            response = [self isAlphaVisibleAtPoint:point forImage:self.buttonBackground];
        }
    }

    self.previousTouchHitTestResponse = response;
    return response;
}
```

---

Another sample code that test if the point is within a layer mask, maybe you can adapt that more easily:

```
@implementation MyView
//
// ...
//
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint p = [self convertPoint:point toView:[self superview]];
    if(self.layer.mask){
        if (CGPathContainsPoint([(CAShapeLayer *)self.layer.mask path], NULL, p, YES) )
            return YES;
    }else {
        if(CGRectContainsPoint(self.layer.frame, p))
            return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}

@end
```

The full article: http://blog.vikingosegundo.de/2013/10/01/hittesting-done-right/

Comment: I have actually downloaded his code from github and looked at the demo.  It seems quite complicated to implement?  the demo does exactly what I need but I'm not sure how to get his code irking with mine.

Comment: Sorry to hear that you find it to complicated. Actually it is straight-forwarded.

Comment: Maybe I'm looking into it too much and not getting it.  Would I need to create an image for each UIButton or would I create an irregular shape and set its background image or what?

Comment: you can create an images in code. or you can figure out how your hitTest might look like.

Comment: actually I totally forgot that I wrote an blog article to show how to do hit testing with triangles. http://blog.vikingosegundo.de/2013/10/01/hittesting-done-right/